# WD Passport 2TB occasional mild clicks

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, clicking-sound

I have a new 2TB external drive formatted as exFAT.. when I started copying data to it, I heard very mild clicks (I know more or less how a failing drive sounds and this was a lot more quiet) and then it stopped... It still happens occasionaly for a few seconds (every few hours or so), but I don't know if that's something newer WD drives just do or I should be worried.

So please tell me if *any* sound like this is a reason to return the drive? Should it not make any quiet clicks at all? I have a similar 1TB WD hdd and I haven't heard such sounds from it...

thank you!
david

Comment: If you are hearing clicks it means there is a physical defect and/or problem with the hdd.  The only sound you should hear is a sound that sounds like a "spinning disk" because thats what a mechanical hdd is made out of ( at the end of the day )

Comment: thank you for the answer... so the reading sound is definitely a bit different from my 1TB Passport drive.... drives look the same, both are USB 3.0, the only difference is size. So maybe this little difference in noise is what I "mistaked" for clicks when hearing for the first time... I mean they are clicks, but very quiet small clicks, present a lot of the time when drive is reading.. So my question now is: could there be a difference in sound and this is normal or do I take the drive back to be sure? It's a hassle to take it back but I really want to be sure my data is safe (as it can be).

Comment: If you hear clicks I cannot be more clear, **clicks are not normal**, I would replace the drive.  If what you hear is not clicks then your data (should) be safe

Comment: okay, I get it - will get it replaced :) I just recorded two videos to compare old and new hdd... and it's pretty obvious from the video (almost more than in real life :) that the new drive is dangerous to rely on. 
[new "clicking" 2TB drive](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95746/hdd_new_2tb.mov)

[old 1TB drive](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95746/hdd_old_1tb.mov)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed an RMA with Western Digital for the same "issue". I received a replacement drive which also makes the same mild clicks occasionally. Replacement drive was running an older firmware version than the one I bought which means they were out of the factory in different batches.

I've run short and extended drive tests using the WD Drive Utilities software. Everything is normal. After copying over 300 GB in each drive, SMART does not report anything abnormal (no errors, no failures).

I'm keeping one of the drives and returning the other one according to the advance RMA agreement. I'm now convinced that the worrisome sound is nothing to worry about :)

It cost me a week in time and $10 shipping to put my mind at ease.

P.S.: It seems that the clicking sound occurs when there is disk activity, reads or writes. I have the impression that it happens mostly during writes but I wouldn't bet on it. However, it seems there is no effect in transfer rate or anything else.

P.S.2: I really do own this exact drive (2TB) model. If anyone said to me over the phone or in some forum that his drive is clicking I would say it's defective right away, like the other guys told you. My guess is though that they do not own this model and are thus drawing general conclusions.

Comment: Its likely the "clicking" sound is the same type of "clicking: sound that you don' want to hear.  I do know that some of the smaller external drives I own vibrate.  Its possible what you are hearing is not the hdd itself that is clicking.

Comment: I still can't get used to the sound.. I'm more or less convinced that it's normal for this particular drive, but it still draws my attention everytime I hear it click.. CRAP.

Comment: From he WD site:

Normal drive sounds include:
Whining noise during drive spin-up

Occasional clicks during data access

Hard clicks during a head park operation (shutdown or sleep mode)
Abnormal drive sounds include:
High-pitched whining sound

Vibration sounds due to either vibration in the mounting hardware or in rare cases, a drive failure

Clicking or clunking sounds that occur repeatedly

Grinding sounds